# What would be the identification reactions of selenate(IV) ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, identification

I have not been able to find any $\ce{SeO3^2-}$ identification reactions anywhere. Are there any?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Classic German AC handbook *Lehrbuch der analytischen und präparativen anorganischen Chemie* by Jander and Blasius lists six different methods (ten if counting various reductants). Where are you determining selenate(IV) content, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reducing agents to reduce the $\ce{SeO3^2-}$ salt to elemental selenium. This paper<sup>1</sup> discusses the use of iron(II) salts in acidic medium (phosphoric - hydrochloric acid) as reducing agent. The reaction proceeds at r.t.

You can use other reducing agents like hydrochloric acid, sulfur dioxide, hydroxylamine hydrochloride, hydrazine hydrochloride. The reduced selenium has a red color which turns greyish-warm on warming, but be careful on overheating (boiling or evaporating turns to serious losses of selenium by forming volatile $\ce{SeCl4}$).

**References**

1. Rajkumar Kalaparthi , Srija Korapu , Padmarao Chekuri, 2020, New Spectrophotometric Determination of Sodium Selenate [Selenium (IV)] and Sodium Selenite[Selenium(VI)] with Iron(II), and Their Quantitative Analysis of Selenium (IV) – Selenium (VI) Present in A Binary Mixtures, INTERNATIONAL JOURNAL OF ENGINEERING RESEARCH & TECHNOLOGY (IJERT) Volume 09, Issue 05 (**May 2020**), DOI: [10.17577/IJERTV9IS050094](https://www.ijert.org/new-spectrophotometric-determination-of-sodium-selenate-selenium-iv-and-sodium-seleniteseleniumvi-with-ironii-and-their-quantitative-analysis-of-selenium-iv-selenium-vi-present-in-a-binary-mixtures)
2. Vogel, A. I., & Svehla, G. (**1996**). *Vogel's qualitative inorganic analysis*